# extract value from json in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-substr

For the below possible JSON values in a column, I need to extract value for CAT attribute
Input Table

```
|  VALUES                                                    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| {"ANIMALS":"1","DOG":"D1","CAT":"C1"}                      |
| {"ANIMALS":"2","DOG":"D2","CAT":"C2"}                      |
| {"ANIMALS":"3","DOG":"D3"}                                 |
| {"ANIMALS":"4","CAT":"C4", "DOG":"D4"}                     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

NOTE: There could be many other non-ordered attributes as a JSON could.

Expected result

```
| CAT     |
-----------
| C1      |
| C2      |
| NULL    |
| C4      |
-----------
```

I've been trying to use something like

`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('{"ANIMALS":"1","DOG":"D1","CAT":"C1"}', 'CAT[^,]+') "REGEXPR_SUBSTR" FROM DUAL;`

which gives me `CAT":"C1"}` for the above input which doesn't fulfil my need to fetch the value.

Comment: I think it's possible to just read the value *as JSON* and then do a query on those properties, instead of using regex that has a chance to match something incorrectly.

Comment: I think you are correct. Why didn't I think about it.
SELECT JSON_VALUE('{"ANIMALS":"1","DOG":"D1","CAT":"C1"}', '$.CAT') AS value
  FROM DUAL
will do the trick

Comment: ... depending on which version of Oracle you are using; JSON support started to be added in 12c. Which version are you on?

Comment: Yes, I am using 12c

Answer (score 1):

As per suggestion, JSON_VALUE will do the trick as the values is a JSON

```
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE('{"ANIMALS":"1","DOG":"D1","CAT":"C1"}', '$.CAT') AS value
FROM
    dual
```

Comment: Only if your are using Oracle 12c or later versions.